# problems with drawing and displaying shapes on images

Tags: java, image, optimization, draw

Please bear with me, english is neither my first nor my second language.

The basic idea is to load images and draw a few shapes using the mouse.
I created these three java classes (see code at the botoom end):

1 Main, right now this is only used to initiate the second class "Action"

2 Action, this class should contain every action the user performs on the ui (drawing, loading images...)

3 UI, this class creates the UI and holds every object concerning the UI (Jlabels, JButtons, JFrame ....)

At this stage it (kinda) works as intended but i have still a few questions. I tried to visualise every problem but i can only use 2 images in this post, so please use this [image](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3783/6vdxozlr_png.htm).

1) Drawing shapes works as itended but as soon as the user creates (releases the mousebutton) the shape it should be displayed in blue colours. This doesn't work unless a new shape is drawn. How can i update the shape after the user releases the button? As seen in the first and second frame of the linked image.
-- **solved**

*added a call to paint(); in the mouseReleased event.*

2) The first shape is darker/a fuller colour than the rest of the shapes, see second and fifth frame in the linked image. I am not sure how to correct this one, any ideas?
--**solved**

exchanged this two lines

```
g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f));
g2d.fill(shape);
```

3) None of the shapes are visiable after resizing the UI, as seen in the third and foruth frame of the linked image. How do i force the program to draw them?
-- **solved**

*added ComponentListener to the JFrame, now calling paint() in the componentResized() event*

3.1) How do i get the shapes to stay within the original image (the black square) after resizing? Fourth frame of the linked image.
-- **solved**

*i forgot to add an offset if the frame was resized....*

4) Checking if the mouse is still within the borders of the image works only if the user doesn't use the scrollpanes. Does anyone have a better idea to check if the mouse is within the image borders?

5) The shapes flicker during drawing if there is more than one shape, i guess because they are drawn everytime the user drags the mouse while drawing. How to fix this problem?

Don't hesitate to point out anything else that is wrong or really the best coding practice.
Thank you in advance.

---

update

-added titels

-changed formating

-added the described changes

---

#### Main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Action();
    }
}
```

#### UIclass

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;


public class UI {
    public JLabel jlabel_image;
    public JFrame jframe_ui;
    public JLabel jlabel_info;

    private Action action;
    private JScrollPane jscrollpane_image;

    public UI(Action action) {
        this.action = action;

        jlabel_image = new JLabel();
        jlabel_image.setHorizontalAlignment(jlabel_image.CENTER);
        jlabel_image.setVerticalAlignment(jlabel_image.CENTER);
        jlabel_image.addMouseListener(action);
        jlabel_image.addMouseMotionListener(action);

        jscrollpane_image = new JScrollPane(jlabel_image);

        jlabel_info = new JLabel("mouse: ");

        jframe_ui = new JFrame("test frame");
        jframe_ui.addComponentListener(action);
        jframe_ui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        jframe_ui.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jframe_ui.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        jframe_ui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe_ui.add(jscrollpane_image, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jframe_ui.add(jlabel_info, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        jframe_ui.pack();
        jframe_ui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

#### Action class

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;


public class Action implements ActionListener, ComponentListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    private UI ui;
    private Point startpoint;
    private Point endpoint;
    private ArrayList<Shape> shapes;
    private boolean mouseonimage;


    public Action() {
        ui = new UI(this);
        shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
        mouseonimage = false;
        BufferedImage bufferedimage = new BufferedImage(800, 800, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = bufferedimage.createGraphics();
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 800);
        g2.dispose();
        ui.jlabel_image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bufferedimage));
    }


    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        paint();
    }


    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(mouseonimage) {
            if(checkMouseCoordinates(me.getPoint())) {
                endpoint = me.getPoint();
                paint();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        checkMouseCoordinates(me.getPoint());
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mouseonimage = true;
        checkMouseCoordinates(me.getPoint());
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mouseonimage = false;
        checkMouseCoordinates(me.getPoint());
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(mouseonimage) {
            if(me.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                if(checkMouseCoordinates(me.getPoint())) {
                    startpoint = me.getPoint();
                    endpoint = me.getPoint();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(checkMouseCoordinates(me.getPoint())) {
            endpoint = me.getPoint();
        }

        if(startpoint != null) {
            if(Math.abs(startpoint.x - endpoint.x) > 9) {
                if(Math.abs(startpoint.y - endpoint.y) > 9) {
                    shapes.add(createrectangle(startpoint, endpoint));
                }
            }
        }

        startpoint = null;
        endpoint = null;

        paint();
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent me) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public boolean checkMouseCoordinates(Point point) {
        boolean withinBoarders = false;

        if(mouseonimage) {
            int imageFrameWidth = ui.jlabel_info.getBounds().width;
            int imageFrameHeight = ui.jlabel_info.getBounds().y;
            int imageWidth = ui.jlabel_image.getIcon().getIconWidth();
            int imageHeight = ui.jlabel_image.getIcon().getIconHeight();
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            int w = imageFrameWidth;
            int h = imageFrameHeight;

            System.out.println(ui.jlabel_info.getBounds());

            if(imageFrameWidth > imageWidth) {
                x = (imageFrameWidth - imageWidth)/2 - 9;
                w = imageWidth;
            }

            if(imageFrameHeight > imageHeight) {
                y = (imageFrameHeight - imageHeight)/2;
                h = imageHeight;

                if(imageFrameWidth > imageWidth) {
                    x = x + 7;
                }

                if(imageFrameHeight > imageHeight) {
                    y = y - 1;
                }
            }

            Rectangle imageFrame = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);

            if(imageFrame.contains(point)) {
                withinBoarders = true;
                ui.jlabel_info.setText(String.format("mouse: on image :: %d/%d :: %d/%d :: %d/%d||%d/%d",point.x, point.y, imageFrameHeight, imageFrameWidth, imageFrame.x, imageFrame.width, imageFrame.y, imageFrame.height));
            } else {
                ui.jlabel_info.setText(String.format("mouse: not on image %d/%d",point.x, point.y));
            }
        } else {
            ui.jlabel_info.setText("mouse: not on image");
        }

        return withinBoarders;
    }


    private Shape createrectangle(Point start, Point end) {
        int image_x = (ui.jlabel_image.getWidth() - ui.jlabel_image.getIcon().getIconWidth()) / 2;
        int image_y = (ui.jlabel_image.getHeight() - ui.jlabel_image.getIcon().getIconHeight()) / 2;
        int image_w = ui.jlabel_image.getIcon().getIconWidth();
        int image_h = ui.jlabel_image.getIcon().getIconHeight();

        int x = start.x;
        int y = start.y;
        int h = end.y;
        int w = end.x;

        x = x < image_x ? image_x : x;
        x = x > (image_x + image_w - 1) ? (image_x + image_w - 1) : x;
        w = w < image_x ? image_x : w;
        w = w  > (image_x + image_w - 1) ? (image_x + image_w - 1) : w;

        y = y < image_y ? image_y : y;
        y = y > (image_y + image_h - 1) ? (image_y + image_h - 1) : y;
        h = h < image_y ? image_y: h;
        h = h > (image_y + image_h - 1) ? (image_y + image_h - 1) : h;

        return new Rectangle2D.Float(Math.min(x, w), Math.min(y, h), Math.abs(x - w), Math.abs(y - h));
    }


    private void paint() {
        Graphics g;
        g = ui.jlabel_image.getGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.drawImage(new BufferedImage(ui.jlabel_image.getIcon().getIconWidth(), ui.jlabel_image.getIcon().getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB), (ui.jlabel_image.getWidth() - ui.jlabel_image.getIcon().getIconWidth()) / 2, (ui.jlabel_image.getHeight() - ui.jlabel_image.getIcon().getIconHeight()) / 2, null);

        for(Shape shape: shapes) {
            g2d.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f));
            g2d.fill(shape);
            g2d.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.draw(shape);
        }

        if(startpoint != null) {
            if(endpoint != null) {
                g2d.setPaint(Color.RED);
                g2d.draw(createrectangle(startpoint, endpoint));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your English is very good if it's your third language :)

Answer (score 0):

For the fist problem you have to repaint in order to see the changes, just add a single line:
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
        endpoint = me.getPoint();

```
    if(Math.abs(startpoint.x - endpoint.x) > 9) {
        if(Math.abs(startpoint.y - endpoint.y) > 9) {
            shapes.add(createrectangle(startpoint, endpoint));
        }
    }

    // Add this line
    paint();

    startpoint = null;
    endpoint = null;
}
```

The second problem, I think is caused because you are telling the graphics to composite the
destination (i.e, the graphics of the image you already have) to have an alpha value of 0.5.
Try to change this code:

```
g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f));
```

for this

```
g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 1.0f));
```

Right now I don't have time, but later I can help you. Also I think there are better ways of achieving that. For example using a Jpanel instead of a Jlabel or an ImageIcon

Comment: thank you! adding the call to paint() solved it. I moved g2d.fill(shape); behind g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f)); after seeing your suggestion for the alpha value. This solved the third question.